# Android DatePickerDialog default date is Jan/1/1900

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I can't figure out this stupid little bug. Whenever I initiate the DatePickerDialog, the default set date date is Jan/01/1900.

It's weird though because on the tablet there's a calendar view next to the slider which you can pick from as well and THATS set on the current date, but the slider isn't.

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("month",Integer.toString(mMonth)); //Is returning current month, like it should

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, mDay, mMonth, mYear); //all set to current date
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        dateDue.setText(month + 1 + "/" + day + "/" + year);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you choose the mDay/mMonth/mYear values?

Comment: onCreate method. But in my Log the month tag is equal to 9, the current month, so that shouldn't be the problem, right?

Comment: Check if the values can be out of bounds to see if the dialog initializes to them. Put mMonth to 14 in runtime with the debugger and wait for the explosion :)

Comment: So now we know those numbers don't influence the default date. Find out why.

Comment: Also this is following http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html pretty closely so I'm not sure why it's happening.

Comment: Try calling public void updateDate (int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) after creation.

Comment: If not, then maybe you're not instantiating this precise child dialog in your xml/inflate/create method?

Comment: I'm an idiot. Order of parameters in constructor is year, month then date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm an idiot. Order of parameters in constructor is year, month then date.